# Using Facebook OpenGraph with profile switched into fanpage

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a fanpage Facebook which was a classic profile. I would like to retrieve the RSS feed thanks to the URL https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=xxx&format=rss20

But when I use this link with my ID it was a "profile page ID-like", not a page ID so the Graph Facebook returns me an error :

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

Anyone with the same problem ?